# Encrypted string has a slash (/) in the result, which causes problems in a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, url-encoding

I hunted around online to find a simple little encryption method that would take a string, encrypt it, and then decrypt it.  The idea being that I have ID's I need in a URL that can't be in plan text.

The class I found workes great most of the time, but sometimes, I end up with an encrypted string that has a / in it:

```
OSprnGR/0os4DQpQsa0gIg==
```

As you can imagine, that causes problems when used in a URL.  So I thought that if I just UrlEncode the string, that it would solve the problem.

It didn't.

I still get the same error even when the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:54471/BrokerDashboard/BuyingLeads/LeadView/OSprnGR%2f0os4DQpQsa0gIg%3d%3d
```

Instead of this:

```
http://localhost:54471/BrokerDashboard/BuyingLeads/LeadView/OSprnGR/0os4DQpQsa0gIg==
```

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Here's the class I'm using:

```
public static class Encryption
{
    public static string keyString { get { return "6C3A231C-57B2-4BA0-AFD6-306098234B11"; } }
    private static byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("somerandomstuff");

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyString, salt);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new CryptoStream(ms, new RijndaelManaged().CreateEncryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16)), CryptoStreamMode.Write));
        sw.Write(plainText);
        sw.Close();
        ms.Close();
        string beforeUrlEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        string afterUrlEndcoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(beforeUrlEncoded);
        return afterUrlEndcoded;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string encrypted)
    {
        //string urlDecoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encrypted); // <--- Turns out you don't need this
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyString, salt);
        ICryptoTransform d = new RijndaelManaged().CreateDecryptor(key.GetBytes(32), key.GetBytes(16));
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        return new StreamReader(new CryptoStream(new MemoryStream(bytes), d, CryptoStreamMode.Read)).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BrokerLead",
    url: "BrokerDashboard/BuyingLeads/LeadView/{id}"
);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` instead of `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`?

Comment: Just confirming that you already read Wikipedia article about bade64 and discarded possibility to use url safe version of it. I would recommend clarify that in the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - does .NET have the ability to use URL Safe Base64 encoding?

Comment: No. But there are plenty of answers showing how to do that...

Comment: I've rolled back your invalid edit that added answer to the question. If you feel separate answer is needed add it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/` character is reserved and cannot be used in the path portion. If this is the last segment of your url you could use the following routing to make it work (notice the `{*id}` segment):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Another approach consists in replacing this character with some other when encrypting/decrypting but in general you should avoid special characters in the path portion of the url and simply put them as a query string where you can properly url encode everything.

Comment: see edit to my OP which includes the route.  So, replacing {id} with {*id} would solve the problem?

Comment: Nope.  Now I get "The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required."

Comment: Does your route pattern look like this `"{controller}/{action}/{*id}"`?

Comment: @Evk, he doesn't replace it, he just url encodes the `/` turning it into `%2f` which will have zero effect in this case. For this to work he needs to actually replace it with a character that is allowed in the path portion of an url, like `-` or `_` for example. But personally I wouldn't recommend this approach as now it is `/` tomorrow it will be something else. If you cannot control the characters that are part of this path segment then you'd better send them as query string parameters.

Comment: I don't understand still. His url is "OSprnGR%2f0os4DQpQsa0gIg%3d%3d" which contains slashes but they are url-encoded. When this string is decoded, his "id" variable will contain "OSprnGR/0os4DQpQsa0gIg==". Why is this not the case?

Comment: When url encoded, the resulting string contains `%2f`. In ASP.NET `%2f` or `/` are treated the same way. ASP.NET MVC thinks that it is path separator and unless you use the technique shown in my answer when defining your route patterns this will not work.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov -- You said, "but in general you should avoid special characters in the path portion of the url and simply put them as a query string where you can properly url encode everything."  This is what I ended up doing. And it works.

Comment: Interesting... Any idea why it does that? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: No, it's not a bug at all. It's perfectly normal. There are characters that simply have special meaning when used in the url and `/` is one of them. And that's the reason, I repeat one more time, query strings should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not the best way to solve the problem but it should work.

After this line:

```
string beforeUrlEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
```

You can replace slashes(`/`) by some other symbols (several symbols):

```
string replacement = "ItIsSlashReplacement";
beforeUrlEncoded = beforeUrlEncoded.Replace("/", replacement);
```

Now you will get string without redundant `/`. I.e, you have encoded string `"abc/dce"`. After replacement you will have `"abcItIsSlashReplacementdce"` - without `/`.

Then when you need to decode string you should reverse your replacement:

```
string replacement = "ItIsSlashReplacement";
string originalEncodedString = stringWithReplacement.Replace(replacement, "/");
```

You get `"abcItIsSlashReplacementdce"`, restore original - `"abc/dce"` and then decode it.

**NOTE:** You can choose as replacement some string and encode it to `base64`. But string should be chosen by the way so after decoding it shouldn't contain `/`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines,  but was wondering that to use to replace the / that I know would work in every situation.  Meaning... I need some string in "replacement" that won't end up inside a Base64 encoded string naturally.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, you can choose some `replacement` and encode it to `base64` too, but encoded replacement should be without `/`, then replace `/`. In this case you insert one base64 inside another.